# Get substring between two indexes of a HTML fragment

Tags: powershell, substring, html-parsing

What is a best way to get the substring within a URL in powershell ?

Given `<a href="http://somehost.aa.com/something?id=12345">http://somehost.aa.com/something?id=12345</a>`

I need to use powershell to extract `12345` as a variable.
I do not know if the length of that substring will remain constant or not - so it could be ***123*** or it could be ***12345689AABCD***

I do know that the URL's href inside "" and link text (a>Link Textwould be the same -  that is Link.  (if it matters)

I tried to use the `IndexOf` methods.. seems , but .. am not sure if there is a way to get substring between two indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **quick-and-dirty [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) solution** using PowerShell's [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator. However, note that regex-based parsing of HTML is invariably limited and brittle and **should be limited to simple cases** such as these:

```bash
$htmlFragment = '<a href="http://somehost.aa.com/something?id=12345">http://somehost.aa.com/something?id=12345</a>'

# -> '12345'
$id = 
  if ($htmlFragment -match '\?id=(\w+)') { 
    # Match found; output the value of the capture group that captured the ID.
    $Matches.1 
  }
```

A **proper, robust HTML-parsing solution** requires quite a bit more work:

Note:

- The solution below relies on the `ConvertFrom-Html` cmdlet from the third-party [`PSParseHTML`](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSParseHTML) module, which you can install with `Install-Module PSParseHtml`, for instance.  The module uses the HTML-parsing API of the [HAP (HTML Agility Pack)](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/) by default, as used below.

```bash
# Needed for [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString()
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$htmlFragment = '<a href="http://somehost.aa.com/something?id=12345">http://somehost.aa.com/something?id=12345</a>'

# Parse the fragment into a HTML DOM.
$node = ConvertFrom-Html -Content $htmlFragment

# Extract the element's inner text, containing the URL.
$url = $node.InnerText

# Parse the URL and its query-string part, then extract the 'id' entry.
# -> '12345
$id = 
  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString(
    ([uri] $url).Query
  ).Get('id')
```

Comment: Thank you.  First part is good enough .. I don't have a complete html, just the <a href=..> part in this case.  Getting an updated item from the vendor's webhook, and they do not provide unique id, but a link to an item.  So, I needed to parse it out.  
It worked.